# fb login api logout error when i use my own button to logout and want to open my Mainactivity

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-activity, facebook-login

Iam using facebook login api to login after sucessfully logging in now i want to logout my user not by facebook login button bu by my own button 
by using this code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            Intent i=new Intent(Mapsstuff.this,Login.class);
            startActivity(I);
        }
    });
```

After i execute it my app started crashing now i remove this code but still my app is crashing and this is showing in my logcat

> 10-22 19:00:38.806 10964-10964/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ab.cleano, PID: 10964
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ab.cleano/com.example.ab.cleano.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.AccessToken.getUserId()' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.AccessToken.getUserId()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.ab.cleano.Login.onCreate(Login.java:168)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7003)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

How to solve it please help

Comment: Make sure your sdk is initialized before hand. You can check if the user is logged in before logging out. Just fyi, you should avoid using your own button OR extremely customize facebook provided login button for ease, it violates there policy and may disable your app authentication any time. (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ , some details on number 8)

Comment: so how should i logout user from navigation drawer activity ? i already set the facebook login button view to not visible if a user is logged in what to do app is still crashing @Jimmy

Comment: try adding `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` on the first line of the onClick, before you access `LoginManager` .

Comment: I have removed that button and it's code it is still crashing

Comment: I initialized sdk but still same issue app is crashing

Comment: Please check "java.lang.String com.facebook.AccessToken.getUserId()" why it coming null, This error will be solved your app crashed Issue.

Comment: yes yogesh i finally managed to gat back to parent activity but now when i login it is crashing dont know but it is giving error of null pointer exception